# Clipped Notify OSD

Tags: notify-osd, fglrx

For the last few weeks I've been having some problems with my Notify OSD.The right and bottom side are clipped. I've tried to reinstall notify OSD several times but without luck.

I've tried to look all over the place on how to resolve this problem and the only thing I keep finding is xorg-edgers related, saying that the latest pixman didn't work and you needed to download an older version. Which they have removed.

I've also purged and removed xorg-edgers content months ago. Videocard I use is an ATI Radeon HD 4350 which isn't a videocard at the top of the list when it comes to support :)

Currently using ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver.

Comment: Did you remove the xorg-edgers PPA using ppa-purge? Have you made sure that it worked (ie, are there any related packages in the  "Installed (local or obsolete)" section of Synaptic)?

Comment: yes, used ppa-purge and I can't see any related packages in Synaptic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to it. Downgrading pixman-1-0 to pixman-0.18.4-1.

```
sudo apt-get install libpixman-1-0=0.18.4-1
```